# problem transforming pgr route to a line - unexpected extra lines from St_MakeLine

Tags: qgis, postgis, pgrouting, routing

I have created a line geometry from a pgr_dijkstra querry and I am getting an unexpected looking line in qgis.  The following image illustrates the problem:

[image]

The magenta line is the line created from mapping the route from my table where I have created a line geometry using the following code:

```
update analysis.routing
set
routeline = (select st_makeline(pgr.geom) ,
from (select * from pgr_dijkstra('ways',61789,64493)) as pgr)
```

The dotted red line is the line created in qgis from calling the same select statement in the DB manager and adding the results to canvas:

```
select * from pgr_dijkstra('ways',61798,64493)
```

Does anyone have any recommendations on how to fix this problem with ST_MakeLine.  That is what appears to be the problem.  It looks like ST_MakeLine is connecting additional points which is adding the additional lines above that are not part of the pgr network.  Thanks for your help.

Comment: Can you please post your full query? I'm having trouble understanding what's happening here, since pgr_dijkstra doesn't return a geom column yet your query is referencing "pgr.geom". Do you have a join to your original geometry table which you've omitted here?

Comment: apologies, I have implemented the function as described here in section 8.3 [pgrouting workshop](http://workshop.pgrouting.org/chapters/wrapper.html#return-route-with-network-geometry) where the pgr_dijkstra returns seq, edge, geom(linestring) as the result in a table, negating the need for joining back to the ways table

Comment: ok - if you run your query: "select * from pgr_dijkstra('ways',61789,64493)", are the sequences in order? ie, is seq sequential?

Comment: yes it is in order.  the function definition from the pgrouting workshop has an order by seq call at the end of it

Answer (score 2):

For someone trying to solve a similar issue, an official solution to the directionality problem (pointed to by Daniel Kastl) exists. Exercise 8 in Geometry Directionality from the [PostGIS tutorial](https://workshop.pgrouting.org/2.5/en/chapters/SQLfunction.html#exercise-8-geometry-directionality) shows how to do it.

Code below in case the link does not work:

```
WITH
dijkstra AS (
    SELECT * FROM pgr_dijkstra(
        'SELECT gid AS id, * FROM vehicle_net',
        (SELECT id FROM ways_vertices_pgr WHERE osm_id = 252643343),
        (SELECT id FROM ways_vertices_pgr WHERE osm_id = 302057309))
),
get_geom AS (
    SELECT dijkstra.*, ways.name,
        -- adjusting directionality
        CASE
            WHEN dijkstra.node = ways.source THEN the_geom
            ELSE ST_Reverse(the_geom)
        END AS route_geom
    FROM dijkstra JOIN ways ON (edge = gid)
    ORDER BY seq)
SELECT seq, name, cost,
    degrees(ST_azimuth(ST_StartPoint(route_geom), ST_EndPoint(route_geom))) AS azimuth,
    ST_AsText(route_geom),
    route_geom
FROM get_geom
ORDER BY seq;
```

The important construct in the above query is:

```
   CASE
      WHEN dijkstra.node = ways.source THEN the_geom
      ELSE ST_Reverse(the_geom)
   END AS route_geom
```

i.e. reverse the geometry if the Dijkstra node is not the source and leave as is otherwise. I then used it for `ST_MakeLine()` and things appear peachy for now.

The solution used by EconGeo did not work for me as `ST_MakeLine()` would not work on multilinestring returned from `ST_Collect/ST_Union`.

Answer (score 1):

In my opinion trouble is that st_makeline function is making line from set of edges that have different directions. I'm using function ST_Union to join edges and don't have this problem. Maybe you should use this function insted.

Comment: Yes, that is what I ended up doing and it works.  But your description totally makes sense of why it would draw those weird lines not on the network,must have been a reverse direction edge in there and linked them up backwards in the st_makeline call. I had to do a st_multi(st_union)) since some of my routes only had one edge and it didn't like linestrings in a multilinestring column.  Currently at 33671425 ms.  Only need to do it once on my data since it's research.  I also noticed that once I do ST_union and get my multilinestring I can knit it together with st_makeline and it works.