# Combining the output of ST_Collect/ST_Union to create linestring from multilinestring?

Tags: postgis, pgrouting, shortest-path

I am using `pgr_dijkstra()` to compute the shortest path and then using `ST_Collect (or ST_Union)` to get the shortest path geometry. However, the collection returned from the `ST_Collect` is a multi-linestring and not amenable to my further analysis which includes using functions like `ST_LineLocatePoint` etc. which need a linestring as an argument.

I am having to use `ST_Collect()` instead of `ST_MakeLine()` directly on the `pgr_dijkstra` output as `ST_MakeLine` ends up connecting the sub-geometries out of order resulting in a garbled line ([described here](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/334302/pgr-dijkstra-gives-wacky-routes-sometimes-with-undirected-graph?)).

Function code:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION public.sp_od(
    orig integer,
    dest integer)
    RETURNS TABLE(shortest_path geometry) 
LANGUAGE 'sql'

AS $BODY$   

SELECT st_makeline(geom) as shortest_path
FROM pgr_dijkstra(
    'SELECT id, source, target, st_length(geom, true) as cost FROM public."WA_roads"',
(SELECT source FROM public."WA_roads"
 ORDER BY ST_StartPoint(geom) <->
     (select ST_SetSRID(ST_MakePoint(CAST(ocentx as double precision), CAST(ocenty as double precision)), 4326) from all_trips_non_zero where origin = orig LIMIT 1) ASC
LIMIT 1),
(SELECT source FROM public."WA_roads"
 ORDER BY ST_StartPoint(geom) <->
     (select ST_SetSRID(ST_MakePoint(CAST(dcentx as double precision), CAST(dcenty as double precision)), 4326) from all_trips_non_zero where destination = dest LIMIT 1) ASC
LIMIT 1), directed := false
) as pt
JOIN public."WA_roads" rd ON pt.edge = rd.id;

$BODY$;
```

I tried using `ST_SnapToGrid()` and `ST_LineMerge()`, still the resulting output from `ST_Collect` is a multilinestring.

I seek suggestions to either get the output from `pgr_dijkstra()` in the right order or for converting the `ST_Collect()` multilinestring to linestring.

Comment: You're looking to UN-combine the multipart features, so you want to research using `ST_Dump`.

Comment: `ST_Dump` takes a step back to individual geometries that I combined using `ST_Collect`. I need a single line (shortest path) that I want to perform operations.

Comment: ST_Collect does not do anything other than combine the geometries into an array. There is no inherent ordering, and no geometric unioning. pgr_dijkstra will return node pointers in the correct order. Please post some code, because what you are saying makes absolutely no sense at all.

Comment: @JohnPowell: Edited the question with code for the function used, also see linked question: https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/334302/pgr-dijkstra-gives-wacky-routes-sometimes-with-undirected-graph for detailed issue.

Comment: @JohnPowell: The issue I am facing seems to be as prophecized here: https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/96090/18956 . The directions of the individual segments are not the same as the traversed path.

Comment: What seems to work is instead of getting the line geom from the "WA_roads" table, if I use the point geom from the vertices table to create makeline. i.e. `JOIN public."WA_roads_vertices_pgr" rd ON pt.node = rd.id;` I have 300k+ OD pairs. How do I make sure this works for all of them?

Comment: @JohnPowell: This isn't correct either, making a line using st_makeline from points just draws the straight line between points, where originally the network could have had a curved line.

Answer (score 1):

[`ST_LineMerge`](https://postgis.net/docs/manual-3.3/ST_LineMerge.html) can now merge lines that have different orientations, using the optional `directed` parameter.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

This is not the answer to your question but I cannot comment right now. what I think the problem is there in your network data geometry. They are not snapped to each other properly. So that's why when you use st_linemerge it is still giving you multilinestring
Try  ST_NumGeometries on your multilinestring output and you will get the number of geom in your ouput.You can also use ST_GeometryN to select a part of your multilinestring and see where there is error